# mongodb embedded vs referance for storing comments or messages

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I what to store message in single document ( embedded ) like this.

```
 Message : 
      _id : 1,
      name : "java",
      message : [ 
         { sender : User_1 , message : "Hello" },
         { sender : User_2 , message : "World" },
      ]
```

I think this doc doesn't expend up to 16MB. Because Only 2 users will message each other and this conversation will delete within 4 weeks.

So is there any side affect of storing message like this and not ( reference ) like so .

```
conversation : 
        _id : 001,
        name : "JavaScript",
        users : [ User_1 , User_2 ] 

Message :
        { _id : 01 , conversationId : 001 , sender : User_1, message : "Hello" },
        { _id : 02 , conversationId : 001 , sender : User_2, message : "World" }
```

And what is most recommended and has more advantages? If document size does not expend up to 16Mb.

Comment: `what is most recommended` - neither, both approaches have pros and cons.  The best approach is what gives your application the necessary performance while minimizing the effort required to maintain it.  Many implementations of this wind up using a hybridized approach where some messages are imbedded and some are referenced.